# how to write the typescript code on two relational tables data in angular 2 application

Tags: api, angular, typescript

I am developing angular 2 application, in my current project I implemented the functionality as lookup master and lookup details strategy using API concept.

In My angualr2 application I get the data from those tables using Http Get request, but I want to bind the data in my view like as LookTypevalue when there is an match of LookupMasterId equals to LookupMasterFkId.

My tables structure like this below.

```
context.LookupMasterTables.AddOrUpdate(

            new LookupMasterTable() { ID = 1, LookupType = "AssetType"},
            new LookupMasterTable() { ID = 2, LookupType = "IntendedUse" },
            new LookupMasterTable() { ID = 3, LookupType = "VehicleYear" },
            new LookupMasterTable() { ID = 4, LookupType = "VehicleMake" },
            new LookupMasterTable() { ID = 4, LookupType = "VehicleModel" }

         );
        context.LookupDetailsTables.AddOrUpdate(

           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 1, LookupValue = "Auto", LookupMasterFKId=1 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 2, LookupValue = "MotorCycle", LookupMasterFKId = 1 },

           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 3, LookupValue = "Personal", LookupMasterFKId = 2 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 4, LookupValue = "Business", LookupMasterFKId = 2 },

           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 5, LookupValue = "1999", LookupMasterFKId = 3 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 6, LookupValue = "2000", LookupMasterFKId = 3 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 7, LookupValue = "2001", LookupMasterFKId = 3 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 8, LookupValue = "2002", LookupMasterFKId = 3 },

           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 9, LookupValue = "Honda", LookupMasterFKId = 4 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 10, LookupValue = "Victory", LookupMasterFKId = 4 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 11, LookupValue = "Indian", LookupMasterFKId = 4 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 12, LookupValue = "Harley-Davidson", LookupMasterFKId = 4 },

           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 9, LookupValue = "Octane", LookupMasterFKId = 5 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 10, LookupValue = "BMW", LookupMasterFKId = 5 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 11, LookupValue = "Audi", LookupMasterFKId = 5 },
           new LookupDetailsTable() { ID = 12, LookupValue = "Swift", LookupMasterFKId = 5 }

        );
```

My html(view) like this below figure.
[image]

[image]

Can you please tell me how to do that.

-Pradeep

Comment: in html how you want it to look like?

Comment: Can you please look at my updated question once.

Comment: How is view related to data you have provided?

Comment: Can you please look at my updated question once